# Using regular expressions to identify nodelists

Tags: php, regex

The following information should be splitted in two arrays:

- foo089,bar[120-123,215]

The desired result is two arrays with all the listed numbers in it [089] and [120-123,215] (even better would be 120,121,122,123 instead of 120-123, this is optional).

Other examples which should be parsed:

- foo[133,370,390-391],bar120
- foo123
- bar145
- bar[121,303]
- foo123,bar145

These all should result in a two-elemented array (first is foo, second is bar), with either a single entry (e.g. 123 or 145) or ranges (e.g. 133,370,390-391 or 121,303).

I always need two arrays, to easily determine whether the number belongs to foo or bar.

**Restrictions**

- foo or bar don't have to exist
- if both exist, they are always ordered
- the numbers always have 3 digits
- there are only foo and bar, no other words
- foo234,foo425 is NOT allowed. If foo or bar has more than one number, it is listed in brackets

I tried the following regex so far: `\d{3}|foo\d{3}|bar\d{3}|\d{3}-\d{3}`. 
However, with preg_grep in php I don't get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?!foo\d{3},bar\d{3})(?:foo(\[(?:\d{3}(?:-\d{3})?,?)+\]|\d{3}))?,?(?:bar(\[(?:\d{3}(?:-\d{3})?,?)+\]|\d{3}))?$
```

Now in the match result, the first group is the numbers for `foo` and the second group is the numbers for `bar`.

Explanation:

1. `(?:\d{3}(?:-\d{3})?` - **three digits** or **three digits**, **dash**, **three digits**
2. `(?:\d{3}(?:-\d{3})?,?)+` - the above repeated multiple times, possibly separated by a **comma**
3. `\[(?:\d{3}(?:-\d{3})?,?)+\]` - same things but in **square brackets**
4. `|\d{3}` - alternatively, just **three digits**
5. `(?:foo(\[(?:\d{3}(?:-\d{3})?,?)+\]|\d{3}))?` the above, but preceded by `foo` and made optional with `?`
6. `,?` - optional **comma** to separate *foo* and *bar*
7. The *bar* part is pretty much the same as one for *foo*
8. `(?!foo\d{3},bar\d{3})` - disallow things like *foo123,bar456*
9. `^$` - match from start to end

[See it in action here](https://regex101.com/r/hK0lS1/1)

Comment: Looks good! However, I'm not able to extract the information from my string in php. How do I get two arrays out of this regular expression?

Comment: When you match, the first group result will be the numbers for *foo* and the second - for *bar*. Aka for `foo089,bar[120-123,215]` first group returns `089` and second group returns `[120-123,215]`.